# Access Zoho Commerce API through some sort of embedded form to add items to cart

Tags: zoho, zoho-deluge

I want to create a form or an app on Zoho Commerce that recommends a set of products to a customer that they can then click a button to add to their cart.

I can figure out the app (I'm assuming I'll have to use dynamic content) but I don't know how to add the items to the cart using the zoho commerce cart api.  I'm fairly new at this.

Any guidance or direction would be greatly appreciated.